# Global allocation functions and const void*

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Does the code below constitutes "undefined behavior" according to C++11 (due to the use of const_cast, see the quote below)?

```
const void* p = operator new(123);
operator delete(const_cast<void*>(p));
```

A relevant quote from C++11 standard (3.7.4.2.3):

> The value of the ﬁrst argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no eﬀect. Otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned if the value supplied to `operator delete(void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new(std::size_t)` or `operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library

If the answer is no, please provide the quotes from C++11 standard that confirm that.

Comment: I don't understand why you cast `p`

Comment: I don't get it. The value passed to `operator delete` *is* one returned by `operator new`, exactly as required. You're free to cast it back and forth however you want inbetween.

Comment: @EoiFirst Because the OP is calling `operator delete`, and not using a `delete` expression.

Answer (score 4):

It's not undefined. The reasoning is this:

1. `operator new` returns `void*`, so it is guaranteed to return modifiable (non-const) memory: [support.dynamic]

   > ```
   > void* operator new(std::size_t size);
   > ```
2. `const_cast` which casts away constness is valid if the object referred to is not const: [expr.const.cast]§7, referring to [dcl.type.cv], particularly §3+4

   > 3 A pointer or reference to a cv-qualified type need not actually point or refer to a cv-qualified object, but it
   >   is treated as if it does; a const-qualified access path cannot be used to modify an object even if the object
   >   referenced is a non-const object and can be modified through some other access path.
   >
   > 4 Except that any class member declared `mutable` (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
   >   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.
3. `const_cast` does not modify the value of the operand: [expr.const.cast]§3:

   > ... The result of a pointer
   >   `const_cast` refers to the original object.

Comment: Does the fact that "The result of a pointer const_cast refers to the original object." mean that it is "one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either operator new[...]"?

Comment: Well, the text only guarantees that the pointer points to the same object. I am wondering if you can have two different values of a pointer type (two different addresses) that point to the same object. 3.9.2/3 "A valid value of an object pointer type represents either the address of a byte in memory (1.7) or a null
pointer (4.10).". In practice, I think in some systems you can actually map the same memory on two addresses.

Comment: @zch Exactly my thoughts, zch, unfortunately without a guarantee from the standard that two pointers with the different value cannot point to the same memory the Angew answer is not convincing (and my example code is probably an undefined behavior).

Comment: @PowerGamer there is absolutely no way that your example code is undefined.

Comment: @zch What about 1.7.1 "Every byte has a unique address."? Does that mean that same byte cannot have more than 1 unique address?

Comment: @PowerGamer, I just wanted to point you to that, but I am not sure. Does "Every X has unique Y" mean only that distinct Xs have distinct Ys or also that every X has exactly one Y?

Comment: @PowerGamer, "Every byte has a unique address" means, at least to me,: (1) a byte cannot have more than one address, and (2) no two bytes can have the same address.